# Accessing a directory with htaccess gives a 500 error

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, xampp, 500-error

I have installed the Xamp server in my Windows machine. I have placed the follwing .htaccess file in a directory :

```
# Original
# If you modify this file then change the above line to: # Modified
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   # Certain hosts may require the following line.
   # If vanilla is in a subfolder then you need to specify it after the /. 
   # (ex. You put Vanilla in /forum so change the next line to: RewriteBase /forum)
   # RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I try to access that directory, it gives me a 500 internal server error! Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don;t write rewrite codes usually but the web server throws 500 when it does not understand what to do.

In your case the rewrite code might be messy, look more on rewrite conditions used in windows.

Try and check the web server log files, it should help as what's causing the error.